# How to combine two vector of vector's along the row?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

I am trying to append a *vector of vector* to another *vector of vector* along the rows, like a `4x4` vector becoming a `4x8` (not `8x4` row/column).

I need directions to make it `4x8`.

`Grid` is an object which holds is made of `Square` objects.

```
Grid CombineGrid(Grid one, Grid two)
{
    vector<vector<Square>> gridOne = one.fields;
    vector<vector<Square>> gridTwo = two.fields;
    vector<vector<Square>> temp;
    int reqCol = one.columns + two.columns, reqRow = one.rows + one.rows;
    temp = gridOne;

    temp.insert(temp.end(), gridTwo.begin(), gridTwo.end());

    for (const auto &row : temp)
    {
        for (Square x:row) 
        {
            cout << "y" << ' ';
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    Grid finalGrid(one.columns + two.columns, two.rows + two.rows);
    finalGrid.fields = temp;

    return finalGrid;
}
```

Comment: if you have a 2D grid that you use a lot consider using something else than `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` there's better suited data-structures out there (a bunch of matrix libraries, or even rolling your own might be better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to conect gridOne[0] (first element of 1st vect) with gridTwo[0] (first element of 2st vect) and some like that for others elements?
If answer is yes, you could try something like that:

```
   size_t grid1Size = gridOne.size();
   for (size_t i = 0; i < grid1Size; i++)
   {
      if(i > gridTwo.size())
      {
         gridTwo.push_back(gridOne[i]);
      }
      else
      {
         gridTwo[i].insert(gridTwo[i].end(), gridOne[i].begin(), gridOne[i].end() );
      }
   }
```